# Set index parameter for Algolia instant search product

Tags: javascript, magento2, algolia

Currently I am working with [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/) autocomplete search template - please see documentation [here](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/autocomplete/js/) and [Magento 2](https://magento.com/).

I want to add index number to each product appeared dynamically when using search input field. It can be added as a [dataset attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). Please see below code and place marked as `data-index="INDEX_NUMBER_HERE"`.

Attribute 'index' should be equal to the search position number. So if in my search results I have 6 products then the first product should has `data-index="1"`, the second one `data-index="2"` and so on until the last one with `data-index="6"`

I know that I can add extra JavaScript code here but maybe someone knows how to do that based on some `{{AlgoliaIndexVariable}}` same as I can fetch in my example {{objectID}}, {{url}}, etc.?

This is my current template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="autocomplete_products_template">
    <a class="algoliasearch-autocomplete-hit" id="productAlgoliaSearch_{{objectID}}" href="{{url}}">
        {{#thumbnail_url}}
            <div class="thumb">img here</div>
        {{/thumbnail_url}}

        <div class="info">
            product info here
        </div>

        <div class="data" data-index="INDEX_NUMBER_HERE"></div>
    </a>
</script>
```

many thanks for useful tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template does expose variable called `__hitIndex` but it's zero based. You can't increment it directly from the template. You can increment it in JavaScript though. You can use the `__hitIndex` for the `data-index` and increment it at the time you retrieve it.